# How to merge/copy entire forked repository into original repository?

Tags: git, github, repository, branch

I had an original repository say 'A' from which I have forked a new repository say 'B'. I have been working on only 'B' since then, where I have created new branches and also deleted few. Now I want to merge my repository 'B' into 'A'.

What I essentially want is if A has (a1, a2, a3) branches and B has (b1, b2, b3) branches I want A (a1, a2, a3, b1, b2, b3) and finally delete forked repo 'B'.

What I initially thought of  was to manually copy each branch of 'B' to 'A' but in that case I will not be able to copy tags that I have created over time in repo 'B'.

Any inputs ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you merge two Git repositories?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1425892/how-do-you-merge-two-git-repositories)

Comment: Why wouldn't you be able to push all tags (just like branches)  from B into A ?

Answer (score 0):

How about trying to create a push request to merge them together?

https://help.github.com/articles/fork-a-repo/

Comment: I'm pretty sure you mean *pull request*